# Return a color from the Themes -> Text Editor panel in Blender

Tags: python, error, theme

When opening *Edit > Preferences > Themes > Text Editor* and hovering over *Line Numbers* color picker, Python Tooltip shows:

```
ThemeTextEditor.line_numbers
```

[image]

How can I read the value? Python reports:

```
AttributeError: type object 'ThemeTextEditor' has no attribute 'line_numbers'
```

Some more info. I am trying to create an addon that can change the Text Editor highlight settings, and then save them. I can save them, but, I can't get the theme colors into my function.

```
def execute( self, context ):
    bpy.ops.wm.save_userpref()
    return {'FINISHED'} #from an operator function

def CreateColorPicker( name, size, prop ) -> FloatVectorProperty:
    return FloatVectorProperty( 
        name = name,
        subtype = "COLOR",
        size = size, #RGB = 3, RGBA = 4
        min = 0.0,
        max = 1.0,
        #default = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
        default = prop
    )

Scene.LineNumbersColor = CreateColorPicker( "Line Numbers", RGB, theme.text_editor.line_numbers )
```

And yes Mr McKenzie your code does work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ThemeTextEditor` is a class and only serves as a blueprint from which you can instantiate objects. You cannot access this attribute on that class directly unless it is [static](https://www.scaler.com/topics/static-variable-in-python/). See [python classes](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp) for more information. You are looking for the instance of type `ThemeTextEditor` which you can access with the following script:

```
import bpy

theme = bpy.context.preferences.themes.items()[0][1]
line_numbers_color = theme.text_editor.line_numbers

print(line_numbers_color)
```

Here's an example how you can modify the color:

```
line_numbers_color.s = 0.8
line_numbers_color.v = 0.8
```